# HiveMQ shared subscriptions using M2Mqtt

Tags: c#, mqtt, hivemq

If subscriber has topic as `$share/group/my_topic`, it doesn't receive any messages, but if I change the topic to `/my_topic` - everything works just fine.

It seems that M2Mqtt doesn't support shared subscriptions. Is there a workaround for this? I also need persistence to work with shared subscriptions.

If there's no workaround, offers to other libraries are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this but I have a theory.

The problem is that you have a leading `/` on your base topic `/my_topic`

If you remove this and publish messages on `my_topic` then the shared topic should match.

Having a leading `/` adds a null element to the topic, which you can't include in the `$share/group/[null]/my_topic`

While leading a `/` is allowed in the MQTT spec it is considered bad practice (and can lead to issues like this).

Also the client library has no knowledge of shared subscriptions, this is entirely a broker side feature. All clients should "just work"

Comment: Actually, removing `/` from topic solved the problem, M2Mqtt works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use MQTTnet library

It can be found at `https://github.com/chkr1011/MQTTnet` or as NuGET package.
It does the job, as far as I've tested!